# Socket.io Client In Android (based on Gottox/socket.io-java-client),How to implement ack of sending messages to server?

Tags: android, sockets, socket.io

I am using socket.io to communicate with my server(using [Gottox/socket.io-java-client](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client?source=c))

I have the question: When I send a message to server,how can I know server recieved the message properly ?
Do I have to let **server send a ack message** to Client so the client knows?
And the point is that In android client,must I make a time-counter with a **time-out** time to wait the ack message ,and if timeout tell the UI the message not successfully send?
Or there's a more elegant way to do so?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check the onMessage event:

```
public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack) {
    try {
         System.out.println("Server said:" + json.toString(2));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```